# Outlook blank 'To' field from Excel VBA on some computers

Tags: vba, excel, email, outlook

We have an Excel spreadsheet that we use to create quotations for potential customers. Through the use of VBA, it generates PDFs and emails them to the customer using Outlook. It takes the customer's email address from a cell on the main sheet where the user fills in the customer's details.

A couple of weeks ago, it stopped filling the customer's email address in the 'To' field in Outlook, even though it had been filled in on the main sheet.

When we change anything on this spreadsheet, including code, we save it as a new 'revision' (keeping all previous revisions.) Going back through the previous revisions, I now find that none of them work. This is odd as they definitely did before. I am using Office 2016 (although I upgraded a while ago, but this issue is recent.) A machine running Office 2013 is also not working. However, a machine running Office 2007 DOES work.

Any ideas as to why this is an issue now, and why it is only an issue on certain versions of Office? Here is a snippet of the code:

```
    Private Sub send_as_pdf_Click()
    On Error GoTo ErrMsg
    Dim strPath As String, strFName As String
    Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object

    strPath = Environ$("temp") & "\"

    strFName = Sheets("Quotation").Name & " " & Range("G18") & ".pdf"

    Sheets("Quotation").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        strPath & strFName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

    strPath2 = Environ$("temp") & "\"

    strFName2 = Sheets("Quotation Offer Letter").Name & " " & Range("G18") & ".pdf"

    Sheets("Quotation Offer Letter").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        strPath2 & strFName2, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

    strPath3 = Environ$("temp") & "\"

    strFName3 = Sheets("Additional Works Required").Name & " " & Range("G18") & ".pdf"

    Sheets("Additional Works Required").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        strPath3 & strFName3, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    strbody = "<p style='color:#2C3E50;font-family:Calibri;font-size:11pt;'>Hi " & Range("C9") & ",</p>"

    strbody2 = "<p style='color:#2C3E50;font-family:Calibri;font-size:11pt;'>The content of the email goes here.</p>"

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .Display
        .To = Range("C19")
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = "first@person.com" & ";" & "second@person.com" & ";" & Range("I6") & ";"
        .Subject = "Quotation"
        .HTMLBody = strbody & strbody2 & .HTMLBody
        .Attachments.Add strPath & strFName
        .Attachments.Add strPath2 & strFName2
        .Attachments.Add strPath3 & strFName3
        .Attachments.Add ("C:\Terms and Conditions of Business of Our Business.pdf")
        .Attachments.Add ("C:\Warranty Statement of Our Business.pdf")
    End With

    Kill strPath & strFName
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
Exit Sub

ErrMsg:
MsgBox ("MUST enter Issue Number, Date & Customer Info."), , "Customer Email Error Message"

End Sub
```

Comment: all other fields are populating okay? It's just the `To` field?

Comment: You may want to reference the range with the sheet that you are using, i.e. `.To = Sheets("NameOfSheet").Range("C19")` ;)

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Yes - the customer's first name populates correctly in the email body, and the third BCC email address populates correctly (this changes based on who is creating the quotation.) It's just that 'To' field.

Comment: @R3uK Unfortunately that didn't work. However, I don't think you need to reference the sheet if it's the active one. Either way, the code above was working up until recently. It also currently works on some other machines.

Comment: @adamcwhite : Indeed, it is implicitly on the active sheet! Still, it is generally better to reference fully a range. I can't see any other thing that could lead to an issue there... Did you try to compare data with `Debug.Print` between working and non-working machines?

Comment: @R3uK I see! I will do this from now on. I haven't tried `Debug.Print`. Forgive me, but how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Comment this line so you can see what the error is and debug.

```
'On Error Resume Next
```

After doing that you should be able to see the error within the line:

```
.To = Range("C19")
```

[image]

In excel this returns the value of the range, however you are sending that value to another application `Outlook` which is expecting a string.

I changed that line to this:

```
.To = Range("C19").Value2
```

and it worked

Comment: This works on all machines. I'm still unsure as to why the problem has only recently presented itself. Thank you so much!